# Adding Emacs-style trailing line comment in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, emacs, visual-studio-code, comments

I am trying to replicate a standard comment shortcut from Emacs in Visual Studio Code (MacOS).

In Emacs, the shortcut `M-;` adds a trailing line comment to the current line. I  use this shortcut quite a lot to comment on parts of the code.

For example, when editing a Matlab script in Emacs, the code

```
A=2*pi*radius;
```

becomes after pressing `M-;`

```
A=2*pi*radius;                          % |
```

where | is the position of the cursor. Is there any way to replicate this behaviour in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

This extension is what you are after. Allows you to use emacs key mappings in vs code.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hiro-sun.vscode-emacs

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I had already tried and that doesn' work. the two comment shortcuts from vscode-emacs either create a comment block (M-;) or comment the current line (Ctrl-;) but they do not replicate the emacs behaviour (add comment at the end of line).